# Detect if a row was modified by an INSERT OR REPLACE?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say we have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
animal VARCHAR NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR,
UNIQUE(colA, colB))
```

And we then do command like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO example (animal, color, name)
VALUES ("animal", "cat", "mittens")
```

Is there a way to tell if the value of the entire row changed at all? For example, if before this command, the table had the following row:

```
animal = "cat", color = "orange", name = NULL
```

It would have changed, since `name` changed.

But if the row before the command was already:

```
animal = "cat", color = "orange", name = "mittens"
```

Then there would be no changes.

Sadly, it seems that the `changes()` function returns `1` in both of these cases. Is there something that would indicate that some value actually changed, or what column(s) changed?

Comment: You would need to write a trigger to calculate this information for each table.

Comment: Possible reference/duplicate for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560000/sql-selecting-rows-where-column-value-changed-from-previous-row

Answer (score 0):

An INSERT commands does not return any information, except for the `rowid` of the new row, which does not help here.

So you have to do a SELECT to get the old values.