# Path from a group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following data:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ group ║ place ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║ a     ║
║  2 ║     1 ║ b     ║
║  3 ║     1 ║ b     ║
║  4 ║     1 ║ a     ║
║  5 ║     1 ║ c     ║
║  6 ║     2 ║ a     ║
║  7 ║     2 ║ b     ║
║  8 ║     2 ║ c     ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

How can I get the path of each group in MySQL?

The expected result is:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ group ║    path    ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║     1 ║ a-b-a-c    ║
║     2 ║ a-b-c      ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Group_concat distinct

Comment: Am I correct that, when sorted by `id`, where a `place` appears more than once in a row for the same `group`, it should only appear once in the `path`, whereas if the `place` appears again not consecutively, it should be in the `path`? For example if the sequence was `a-a-b-b-b-a-b-b-c` it should be simplified to `a-b-a-b-c`?

Comment: @MattRaines, yes  you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the end goal is to sort by `group` and `id`, and then simplify each group's sequence so that consecutive repeated places are only shown once:

Start by determining, for each row, whether the place or the group have changed since the previous row. There's a good solution to this problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565970/5024519).

Then use `GROUP_CONCAT` to merge the places together into a path.

Be aware that `GROUP_CONCAT` has a user-configurable maximum length, which by default is 1,024 characters.

```
SELECT 
    `group`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(place ORDER BY id SEPARATOR '-') path
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE(@place != place OR @group != `group`, 1) changed,
        id,
        @group:=`group` `group`,
        @place:=place place
    FROM
        place_table, (SELECT @place:=NULL, @group:=NULL) s
    ORDER BY `group`, id) t
WHERE
    changed = 1
GROUP BY `group`;
```