# SQL Return last record where column value changed and amount of change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In MS SQL 2012, I have a table like such:

```
    Key    |    Entity    |    Value  |    DateTime
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    10           A              800        1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
    08           A              800        1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM
    06           A              700        1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
    04           A              725        1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
    09           B              550        1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
    07           B              400        1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM
    05           B              400        1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
    03           B              375        1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

I would like to return the date of change and the amount of change -- from the last record where the value changed from the record before it.

Ideally, this:

```
    Entity    |    ValueChange    |    DateofChange
    ------------------------------------------------
    A              100                 1/1/2018
    B              150                 1/1/2019
```

Entity A last changed on 1/1/2018 by 100, Entity B last changed on 1/1/2019 by 150

I'm thinking it's going to be some combination of Lag and maybe this discussion: [SQL: selecting rows where column value changed from previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560000/sql-selecting-rows-where-column-value-changed-from-previous-row)

But I'm very much a SQL beginner and have no formal training, and I appreciate any detail and extra explanations you can provide.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you have negative ValueChange?

Comment: Hard to help as your expected output is not included in the sample data.

Comment: @alexherm the expect output is included.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, it can have a negative value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First with a `CTE` which returns all the changes and then with `NOT EXISTS` that returns the last change for each `Entity`:
(**Edited** with the actual table and column names)

```
with cte as (
  select t.hUnit UnitID, (t.cRent - tt.cRent) cRentChange, t.dtDate DateofChange
  from unit_history t inner join unit_history tt
  on 
    tt.hUnit = t.hUnit 
    and 
    tt.dtDate = (
      select max(dtDate) 
      from unit_history 
      where hUnit = t.hUnit and dtDate < t.dtDate
    )
  where t.cRent <> tt.cRent
)

select c.* from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where UnitID = c.UnitID and DateofChange > c.DateofChange
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c80d6576d617630773a0297179d90b6b).
Results:

```
 Entity | ValueChange | DateofChange       
> :----- | ----------: | :------------------
> A      |         100 | 01/01/2018 00:00:00
> B      |         150 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wasn't able to get it to work. I kept getting an invalid column name error for Entity. I'm not sure where I went wrong in changing the names from your code to mine. The actual table is named unit_history, entity is hUnit, value is cRent, and datetime is dtDate. -- and I guess I don't have enough space in this comment to put the code I used ...

Comment: You can see in the demo that the code works. I used the names that you mention in your question. So you must change all the table and column names accordingly.

Comment: Please help me where I went wrong in changing all the names. I'm even getting the same error on your demo- I think I'm not understanding one of them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a89cf403481b36022ca766b4da772910

Answer (score 1):

One method uses two levels of window functions, one to find the changes and one to get the last change:

```
select t.*, (value - prev_value) as diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by entity order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(value) over (partition by entity order by datetime) as prev_value
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_value <> value
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Where's the "value change"?

Comment: You have two columns in the select. `value` and `prev_value`, just calculate the difference

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what output you want, maybe like this in each row:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Key] int, [Entity] CHAR(1), [Value] int, [DateTime] datetime);

INSERT INTO @T ([Key], [Entity], [Value], [DateTime])


VALUES
    (10,'A',800,'1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(08,'A',800,'1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(06,'A',700,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(04,'A',725,'1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(09,'B',550,'1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(07,'B',400,'1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(05,'B',400,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM')
    ,(03,'B',375,'1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM')

SELECT 
         [Key]
        ,[Entity]
        ,[Value]
        ,[DateTime]
        ,ISNULL(LAG([VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Entity] ORDER BY [Key]),0) as PrevValue
        ,[Value] - ISNULL(LAG([VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Entity] ORDER BY [Key]),[Value]) as Change
FROM @T
ORDER BY [Entity],[Key]
```

Result:

```
Key         Entity Value       DateTime                PrevValue   Change
----------- ------ ----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
4           A      725         2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           0
6           A      700         2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 725         -25
8           A      800         2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 700         100
10          A      800         2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 800         0
3           B      375         2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           0
5           B      400         2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 375         25
7           B      400         2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 400         0
9           B      550         2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 400         150
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help you

```
with cte1 as
(
whatever query you used to make that first table in your question
),
cte2 as
(
select *, lead(Value) over (partition by Entity order by DateTime desc) Prior_value
from cte1
order by Entity, DateTime desc
)
select *, (Value-Prior_value) change
from cte2
```